# Coverity email_defects.py

Tags: email, ldap

I'm using the email_defects.py with Coverity and it will only send emails if I have the users set to local on the CIM (Coverity Integrity Manager).  If it is set to the LDAP it will not send emails as it is trying to send it user@LDAP instead of the actual email address user@.com.

Getting the email is great but if it is set to local, then the user cannot log in because it cannot connect to the LDAP.

How can I receive an email and log in?  Yes I want my cake and be able to eat it too :)

This is the link to the scripts that I am using: 
https://communities.coverity.com/docs/DOC-1252

email_defects.zip 26.0 K

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This script uses CIM's notify web services method.  This method relies on users having valid 'email' field on the server.

You need to check that your LDAP users have valid e-mails and that CIM is configured with correct 'Email attribute' to map your LDAP server's email field to CIM.

Easiest way to check is to go to the system configuration tab in CIM, select your configured LDAP server and double-check that email attribute field is set to something reasonable.

Then go to the Users tab and check that LDAP users who are there have correct email addresses filled in from the LDAP system.